# git remote prune – didn't show as many pruned branches as I expected

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch, git-remote

From the man page:

> ```
> Deletes all stale tracking branches under <name>.
> These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository
> referenced by <name>, but are still locally available in "remotes/<name>".
> ```

So I removed a bunch of branches using

```
git push origin :staleStuff
```

and then ran

```
git remote prune origin
```

However, only one single local branch was pruned. Some of these branches were created by me, some by co-workers. Does this indicate that I wasn't tracking those branches correctly in the first place?

Comment: to find out what branches are going to be removed you can do `git remote show origin` and look for any branches marked `stale`

Answer (score 191, accepted):

When you use `git push origin :staleStuff`, it automatically removes `origin/staleStuff`, so when you ran `git remote prune origin`, you have pruned some branch that was removed by someone else. It's more likely that your co-workers now need to run `git prune` to get rid of branches you have removed.

---

So what exactly `git remote prune` does? Main idea: local branches (not tracking branches) are not touched by `git remote prune` command and should be removed manually.

Now, a real-world example for better understanding:

You have a remote repository with 2 branches: `master` and `feature`. Let's assume that you are working on both branches, so as a result you have these references in your local repository (full reference names are given to avoid any confusion):

- `refs/heads/master` (short name `master`)
- `refs/heads/feature` (short name `feature`)
- `refs/remotes/origin/master` (short name `origin/master`)
- `refs/remotes/origin/feature` (short name `origin/feature`)

Now, a typical scenario:

1. Some other developer finishes all work on the `feature`, merges it into `master` and removes `feature` branch from remote repository.
2. By default, when you do `git fetch` (or `git pull`), no references are removed from your local repository, so you still have all those 4 references.
3. You decide to clean them up, and run `git remote prune origin`.
4. git detects that `feature` branch no longer exists, so `refs/remotes/origin/feature` is a *stale* branch which should be removed.
5. Now you have 3 references, including `refs/heads/feature`, because `git remote prune` does not remove any `refs/heads/*` references.

It is possible to identify local branches, associated with remote tracking branches, by `branch.<branch_name>.merge` configuration parameter. This parameter is not really required for anything to work (probably except `git pull`), so it might be missing.

*(updated with example & useful info from comments)*

Comment: I understood the situation to be: the branches are still present locally but removed from remote repo. Now I want to remove all local branches that do not exist on the remote, therefore I run git prune. That's what "These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository" says to me. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right, but you may have misunderstood the meaning of "local branches" in case of `git prune`. Only branches in `/refs/remotes/<remote_name>/` are subject to pruning; any branches in `/refs/heads/` won't be touched - you have to manually manage these.

Comment: Aha, that's indeed what I thought. So there's no way to do what I want: automatically delete all branches in heads that are tracking remote branches, by checking if those remote branches are deleted?

Comment: There is no built-in command for that, but you may write such script yourself. Tracking branches can be identified by presence of `branch.<branch_name>.merge` config parameter.

Comment: This answer would be better if you added the information in the comments into the answer itself so that everyone who comes here and has the same misconception as @Felixyz doesn't have to look at your answer funny and then read the comments to finally gain understanding.