# Pruning branches that were deleted in upstream Git repo but still exist in my fork

Tags: git, bitbucket

I created a fork of a git repo on BitBucket (let's call it `fork_origin`). Now the upstream repository (let's call it `upstream_origin`) has had numerous branches merged into it's master and deleted. So running

```
git fetch --prune upstream_origin
```

deleted lots of `remote/upstream_origin/` branches, but now those same branches still exist in the `remote/fork_origin/` namespace.

Is there a standard git command to deal with this? I'd like to stay away from complex bash scripts that do mass deletes on the remote repos.

UPDATE:

As suggested, I tried to use the remote prune command:

```
git remote prune fork_origin
```

However, it had no effect. Upon further investigation, that seems to work only for 'stale' branches, but when I run:

```
git remote show fork_origin
```

it shows that all of the branches are still 'tracked'. So it makes sense that the `git remote prune` command had nothing stale to delete. Is there a way to force the remote repo (`fork_origin`) to update it's branch statuses relative to `upstream_origin`?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am running into the same problem

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the branches on the remote use this command:

```
git remote prune fork_origin
```

But before that, take a look at this thread and see what can go wrong: [git remote prune – didn't show as many pruned branches as I expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040717/git-remote-prune-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Comment: I added an update to the question regarding what this command did. Also, these are branches that have no local branch tracking them, so I don't think the issues from the other thread apply to my situation.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux and Mac users this command would delete all branches from my work that have been deleted in upstream.

```
git branch -a | grep origin | awk -F \/ '{print $NF}' > _my_branches.txt; git branch -a | grep upstream | awk -F \/ '{print $NF}' > _upstream_branches.txt; for deleted_branch_name in `comm -23 _my_branches.txt _upstream_branches.txt`; do git push origin :$deleted_branch_name; done
```

If you prefer to have steps instead of one long command:

```
# Find the branches in my fork
git branch -a | grep origin | awk -F \/ '{print $NF}' > _my_branches.txt; 
# Find the branches still in upstream
git branch -a | grep upstream | awk -F \/ '{print $NF}' > _upstream_branches.txt;
# See only the ones that are still in my fork with the comm command
# And only for those branches issue a git command to prunbe them from my fork.
for deleted_branch_name in `comm -23 _my_branches.txt _upstream_branches.txt`; do git push origin :$deleted_branch_name; done
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single git command, but you would need to;

- fetch `fork_origin`
- identify any `remotes/fork_origin/branch` which isn't present anymore in `remotes/upstream_origin` (because of your `git fetch --prune upstream_origin`)
- `git push --delete thoseBranches`

This is a bit similar to "[Delete multiple remote branches in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10555315/6309)".