# How to remove branches already deleted on GitHub that still show up in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, after I do a pull request and delete the branch on GitHub, that branch still shows up in Visual Studio Code. If I select the branch, it gives an Error, as expected.

How do I remove these now-deleted branches from VS Code. Can it be done automatically?

Comment: No need to restart VS Code, just hit the Refresh button in the Source Control menu

Comment: I actually build a function to handle this and write a little article about it. [Link](https://medium.com/@davidhu314/my-favorite-git-alias-to-keep-my-branches-in-check-e0b49b7cbfd5)

Comment: @Drenai why need to user `git branch -d <branch-name>`, for deleting individual branches one by one?

Comment: vs code has setting to always [prune branches during fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65187314/6908282) - `git.pruneOnFetch`

Comment: @Gangula Yes, I mention it [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65187314/6309), with VSCode 1.52+ (Nov. 2020).

Answer (score 336, accepted):

Apparently, this feature is intentional. I found out that a correct way to remove all remote branches that have been deleted from Github is to run the following command.

```
git fetch --prune
```

Then restart visual studio to remove the branches from the command palette

Comment: @Brian, this does not remove any local branches you have. This command removes the `origin/branch_name` from the quick switch git menu on VSCode. For example, if you have a local branch `test` and push it to Github, there are two branches `test`, and `origin/test` on the git branch menu, the prune only removes the `origin/test` branch, not the `test` branch.

Comment: @Brian I found that this would clear the remote deleted branches after a restart of VS Code

Comment: this command doesn't work. I still see all of the branches in the list both when do command `git branch` or click on the branch name to see a dropdown with all available branches

Comment: @AnnaOlshevskaia `git branch` only list the local branches, this command is supposed to remove the `remotes/branch_name` branches. Try `git branch -a` to see everything.

Comment: No need to restart VS Code, just hit the Refresh button in the Source Control menu

Comment: To run this in VS Code, use `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type `Git: Fetch (Prune)` which should do the same thing.

Comment: I can still see the local branches after trying all these methods, what to do , only way is to delete one by one?, i have like 10 not updated branches

Comment: this is only meant to remove remote branches. to remove local branches, you can do `git branch | xargs git branch -d`. or use `-D` if you want to remove ones that are not merged also.

Comment: This answer actually only makes it even harder for you. You still have to delete all the local branches one by one. And since all the remote branches have been removed by the command, there is a dialog `The branch '...' is not fully merged. Delete anyway?`, which you have to accept for every delete.

Comment: Why does this answer have 300 upvotes?

Comment: This won't remove local branches which is the main ask. I wonder why is it getting so many upvotes. It's a basic git command to sync "remote" branches but has nothing to do with local branches.

Comment: the command to delete a local branch is "git branch -D branch-name"

Answer (score 128):

Local branches can be removed from Visual Studio Code by opening the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows/Linux, CMD+Shift+P on Mac) then Selecting **Git: Delete Branch...**. You can then delete the local branch by selecting the appropriate one from the list.

Comment: Haven't test it through, but it seems to only show local branches, so it should work as described.

Comment: @TylerBell As he already says, it is the method of removing the local branch not remote branch.

Comment: this should have been the answer. i don't know why i was so stupid as to not know this myself. thank you @matthew-disney-cook

Comment: Nope, he clearly is talking about a remote branch. OP says after deleting it from a pull request, probably using the web UI or smth, the pull request is completed and the branch is removed (from the server), but still stays locally. So - clearly, he is talking about a synced branch on the server. So - OP was asking to remove the remote branch which shows up locally under "remote branches".

Comment: I think OP is well aware of how to delete branches one by one. That was obviously not his question here. ("Can it be done automatically?")

Answer (score 41):

Open the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows/Linux, CMD+Shift+P on Mac) and select **Git: Fetch (Prune)**.

This [feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/59693) was [merged](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/59735) into VS Code on Nov 20, 2018.

Comment: is there a way to make this default behaviour of git pull in vscode ?

Comment: Yes, you can set `git.pruneOnFetch: true`

Comment: it still doesn't work

Answer (score 22):

Branches removed from GitHub are well... just removed from GitHub. You still have local copy of branch on your machine. To delete local branch run `git branch -d the_local_branch`. There is no command in VS Code to do so, but you can start terminal in VSCode using `View: Toggle Integrated Terminal` command and run command from it.

For more information about branch management please visit git documentation - https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Branching-Branch-Management

Comment: Quite dumb that they do not support native git commands within their git-command line. Badly designed.

Comment: Please see the above answer from @matthew-disney-cook

Answer (score 18):

You don't have to `git fetch --prune` and restart VSCode anymore.
With VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020), you now have:

> ### [Git: Prune on fetch](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/d9a6977d8a5d2c0f9f0fb28227ac4a022d558c3b/release-notes/v1_52.md#git-prune-on-fetch)
>
> Enabling the `git.pruneOnFetch` setting will make VS Code run `git fetch --prune` when fetching remote refs.

No more extra branch locally once they have been deleted from GitHub.

See [PR 89249](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/89249), fixing [issue 86813](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/86813):

> Usage:
>
> ```yaml
> {
>    "git.pruneOnFetch": true
> }
> ```
>
> Setting is `false` by default.
>
> This would add the `--prune` flag to all git fetches.

Comment: I turned this setting on, clicked on `Pull, Push/Fetch (prune)` but I still see all the local branches for which there is no remote :(

Comment: @ekkis [`git prune`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36083638/6309) would remove your local "remote tracking branches", not your local branches. It removes `origin/xxx`, if `xxx` no longer exists in the remote repository.

Comment: This should probably be considered as the answer, since the question is targeted to VS Code and not Git in general

Answer (score 12):

All you need to do is to run this command:

```
git remote prune origin
```

Something extra that you can do, since it's annoying sometimes to open a terminal just for that, is to make that a task in VS Code.

To do that please follow these steps:

1. In VS Code *View > Command Palette* (CMD/CTRL + Shift + P)
2. Type *Configure Task*
3. Select *Create tasks.json file from template* and a new file will be created under *.vscode* folder.
4. Inside the tasks array, add this:

   ```json
   {
       "label": "Git Prune",
       "type": "shell",
       "command": "git remote prune origin",
       "problemMatcher": []
   }
   ```

How to use it:

1. Open the Command Palette
2. Type *Run Task* and select it
3. Select Git Prune

Reference:

1. [Git prune](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune)

Comment: @Drenai No, them are the same. But for a full response look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106712/what-are-the-differences-between-git-remote-prune-git-prune-git-fetch-prune#answer-20107184)

Answer (score 12):

I interpreted the question to be: how can I delete my *local* branches that have been merged, since I've been using Git Fetch (Prune) from the command palette. This may be considered a "hack", but it's what I use. In the PowerShell terminal:

```
$branches = (git branch --merged).replace(" ", "").replace("*", "") | ? { $_ -ne "develop" -and $_ -ne "master" }
foreach ($branch in $branches) { git branch $branch -d }
```

In case you're not familiar with PoSH, here's what that does: the first line gets the name of all merged branches (with the exception of develop and master), and the second line loops through that list and runs "git branch  -d". As long as the branch is merged completely, you should see:

```
Deleted branch <branch name> (was <commit ID>).
```

for each branch. Occasionally I'll run into a branch that fails to be deleted - if this happens, and you're sure that it's safe to be deleted (i.e. you won't lose local work that hasn't been stored), you can run:

```
git branch <branch name> -D
```

Note the capital D - that *forcibly* deletes the local branch.

Comment: There’s a fine line between genius and insanity. This is well away from that line, on the insanity side.

Comment: No it's not.  It's not that complex when you look at it, and anyway, it's just a powershell translation of answers from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged

Answer (score 9):

In the newer version of visual studio 2019 for example 16.8.6 you need to go to settings and find git settings as shown below:
[image]

Comment: This is awesome! thank you for sharing probably the easiest method

Comment: Just FYI - This answer is for Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code. Same question is [asked here for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44392375/6908282)

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to fix this. So you need to remove the remote that links to the Github repo, then add the remote again.

All the branches that are deleted from Github will no longer show up in vscode. Assuming that `origin` is the name for the remote repo.

```
git remote remove origin
```

Then

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:your-username/repo-name.git
```

Comment: not that I know of. It's the only way I found that will remove the remote branches that no longer exists.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove all the local branches (except master) with:

```sh
git branch -r | grep -v "master" | xargs git branch -D
```

And you can remove all the branches still appearing as `origin/XXXX` in VSCode but already deleted in `origin` with:

```sh
git fetch --prune
```

---

Note:

The first command above (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52006270/3120163):

- list all the branches
- remove the master branch from the list
- delete the branches in the list

Comment: I added an explanation @Drenai

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) supports this with `GitLens: Git Branch` -> `prune (deletes local branches with missing upstreams)` or direct shortcut: `GitLens: Git Prune Branches...`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The shorter command is:

```
git fetch -p
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an improvement on the [answer by davidhu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43943885/2745495) which works.

This command removes branches deleted on Github that still show in VS Code. Let's assume that what is inside the braces `[origin]` is the name of the remote repo:

```
git remote remove origin
```

Then

```
git remote add origin **git@github.com:your-username/repo-name.git**
```

or you can remove it manually from VS Code:

1. Click the **source control icon** found on the left side of VS Code
2. Click on the **more icon or more action**, then click on "**Remote**, which will show either "**add remote** " or "**remove remote**"
3. Click on "**remove remote**", which will show you a list of all the remote repositories on your VS Code. You can then pick the one you want to remove and press "Enter"

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of branches which will be available in your local machine.
`git branch -a`

1. Local branches
2. Remote branches

To ensure end to end clean up of all "stale" branches, you can run this little script:

```
git fetch -p | git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|development)" | xargs git branch -d
```

`git fetch -p` will remove all "remote" branches which are no longer available at the origin.

The rest of the command is not exactly what you are looking for but will still cover 99% cases. It will delete all "local" branches except `master`, `development` AND the branch on which you already are.

PS: If you are using windows, install `xargs` linux package for windows installed: https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/releases/tag/v0.8.0

Comment: @Drenai no because there's `git branch --merged` in this command. If you remove it, it will consider all branches including those that are not pushed to remote.

Answer (score -2):

This approach does not directly answer how to address the raised question in vscode. But it's still a valid way to get the same result.

I use [git-removed-branches](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-removed-branches)

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score -2):

In VS Code, just do

```
git branch -d <branch name>
```

or

```
git branch -d <branch name>
```

for unmerged branches.

It will forcefully remove branch names from VS Code.

Comment: Do you mean `git branch -D` in your second command?