# Clear Git branch that doesn't exists in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab

when I working with [gitlab](http://www.gitlab.com), for some feature I create new branch and work on it and after commit,push,merge I remove branch that was I worked on it from gitlab and then click on `Sync` command in VS Code git command to sync. but all of branches that i created and many of them is merge and deleted are still exists in vs code branch list, how to I sync VS Code branch list with git and gitlab or github.
if it's helpful I also using `Git Lens` in VS Code

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to @VonC answer and this [SF Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512124/visual-studio-code-remove-branches-deleted-on-github-that-still-show-in-vs-cod) an alternative solution is run this command in VS Code Terminal or any terminal in your git repository :

```
git fetch --prune
```

Answer (score 0):

That was [requested here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2558) but [PR 25862](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/25862) only implemented the git *local* branch deletion, not the remote one.

[GitLens also requested](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/189) that feature.

For now, you still need to [push the deletion of a local branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/6309) in order to delete the remote one.